# Autostart `slurmd` service on computes after reboot

Tags: systemd, slurm

I am calling `scontrol reboot <nodename>` to reboot compute nodes in my SLURM cluster.

The reboot usually times out (seen from SLURM) and the node is set to state "DOWN".
(RESUME_TIMEOUT is set to 300).

This presumably happens because the `slurmd` service does not autostart itself after boot.
By default, the service is "disabled":

```
[root@c1 ~]# systemctl status slurmd
● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Activating it using `systemctl enable slurmd` does not last after the next reboot, the service is again "disabled" then.
I assume this is because the change does not happen in the image which is used for booting.

How can I enable the `slurmd` service on the computes so that it starts on boot and `scontrol reboot` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a reply from Antanas Budriūnas via the OpenHPC mailing list which solved the issue.

```
(execute on master node)
# chroot /<path>/<to>/<cnode>/<image>
# systemctl enable slurmd
# exit
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the recommended way, but I setup a mini cluster at work and the way I fixed it was with a cronjob:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/scontrol update nodename=[put hostname here] state=resume
```